# Need explaination of this Javascript code

Tags: javascript, user-interface

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function employee(name, jobtitle, born) {
    this.name=name;
    this.jobtitle=jobtitle;
    this.born=born;
}


var fred = new employee("Fred Flintstone", "Caveman", 1970);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = employee.name;
</script>
```

When I execute this code I get output as : employee
But if I execute employee.jobtitle in place of employee.name like:
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = employee.jobtitle

I get output as : undefined.
Why ?

Comment: Try `fred.name` and `fred.jobtitle` instead, as `fred` is the name of your object instance. [An example](http://jsfiddle.net/1kgu2ru1/1/)

Comment: Thanks!!! you are right. But I just wanted to know when we use employee.name we get employee as output, then if we use employee.jobtitle we have to get jobtitle as output right?. why is it showing as undefined?

Comment: I don't see how you conclude that given `employee.name -> employee`, it must be `employee.jobtitle -> jobtitle`. That seems pretty arbitrary. What's the pattern there?

Answer (score 2):

When you ask for `employee.name` what you are in fact asking for is the name of the *function*. Now this appears to be *new* functionality [that has appeared in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), so while this may work in current browsers which have already started implementing the ES6 standards, I'll bet my last fiver that it doesn't work in older browsers like IE8, simply because they don't support ES6.

The reason `employee.jobtitle` returns `undefined` is because there is no native property called `jobtitle` as part of `Function.prototype` unlike `name`.

Remember, `employee` is a constructor, and it's `fred` that's the object instance in this case. `fred.name` and `fred.jobtitle` will give you the property values of that object like you would expect.

Comment: Many browsers have implemented `name` for some time, even if they don't/didn't support ES6.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't really have the energy to check, but that's interesting to know. Cheers, @FelixKling.

Comment: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#function_name_property ... but you are right, IE is not one of them ;)

Answer (score 0):

`employee` is a function, it doesn't have a `name` property.

`fred`, on the other hand, is an object which was built by that function.  It *does* have a `name` property.

Try:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fred.name;
```

In object-oriented programming, you reference specific instances of a type to interact with them.  Not the type itself.